# PgAdmin4 cant find pgagent as an extension MacOS

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, pgagent

I installed **pgagent** using **EnterpriseDB**'s installer on MacOS. However, pgagent doesn't show up in pgadmin after the installation. Even when I try to manually add pgagent as an extension, I get the error:

> extension "pgagent" is not available and that pgadmin "Could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory"

Here are the installed pgagent files inside the mentioned directory, so I don't understand why it's not recognizing it.

[image]